# Chrome: Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/gif

Tags: google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing a REST service using ASP.NET MVC 5.. here is a simplified code:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/v1/qrcode")]
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Location = OutputCacheLocation.None)]
public FileContentResult GenerateNewQrCode(int height = 200, int width = 200)
{
    byte[] qrcode  = ... some qrcode generation logic here ...

    return new FileContentResult(qrCode.ToArray(), "image/gif");
}
```

**You can try the API here**: http://13.76.95.11:81/api/v1/qrcode

But Google Chrome keep displaying `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/gif` in the console...

[image]

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind... this warning appears only if I type the image URL into the address bar directly...

No warning will appear if the image URL is referenced via `<img src="....` attribute (this is the intended use anyway).

So I guess Chrome assumes whatever we type in the URL bar will be of type `Document` but receiving image instead.